# Typescript return type of factory method in base class

Tags: class, typescript, oop, inheritance

Coming from a Python background, I encountered a few problems while trying to make Typescript happy with the following inheritance model.

Given the following base class:

```
// model.ts
export class Model {

    serialize() {}
    static deserialize(dbRow) {}

    static async filter(options) {
        const dbRows = await getData(options);

        return dbRows.map(row => this.deserialize(row));
    }
}
```

and the following class extending it:

```
// user.ts
export class User extends Model {
    serialize() {......}

    static deserialize(dbRow) {......return new User(......)}

    someOtherMethod() {.....}
}
```

How could I define Model.filter so that `const users = await User.filter({.....})` will automatically infer the type of users as User[]? Right now, the inferred type is Model[].

I know I can do `const users = <User[]> await User.filter({....})` but I wonder if there is any way of suggesting the return type of Model.filter as the class constructor so that instances of child classes will be inferred correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following workaround (mentioned several times in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)):

```
type ModelContructor<T> = new () => T;

class Model {
    // ...
    static async filter<T extends Model>(this: ModelContructor<T> & typeof Model, options): Promise<T[]> {
        const dbRows = await getData(options);

        return dbRows.map(row => this.deserialize(row));
    }
}
```

Here we use fake `this` parameter, which enforces `T` to be resolved as `User` when `User.filter` called.

Comment: Thanks! The thread you linked really helped get an idea of what others were doing to solve this. I'll stay with type hints for now because the solutions I've tried from that thread also force me to define `Model.deserialize` in a similar way. This wouldn't be so painful if `deserialize` wouldn't have implementations in child classes, but that's exactly what will happen. 
Seems a bit harsh to force this on all users of this class.

Comment: Why do you need to define `Model.deserialize` in similar way? Works for me as is

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Model` generic:

```
// model.ts
export class Model<T> {
    ...
    static async filter(options): Array<T> {
        const dbRows = await getData(options);

        return dbRows.map(row => this.deserialize(row));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
// user.ts
export class User extends Model<User> {
   ... 
}
```

You can read more about Typescript's generics [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: From Typescript's documentation: "Generic classes are only generic over their instance side rather than their static side, so when working with classes, static members can not use the class’s type parameter."

Comment: OK, I assumed that's a repository pattern (OOP) and `filter` is an instance method. I get why i.e. `deserialize` is a static method, but don't get why filter must be static.