# TypeScript factory method on parent class return child class type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a factory method on a parent class which is extended by several child classes.

What I'd like to do is define the factory method on the parent, since it doesn't need to change, and have it return the correct type for the child which has extended it.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(protected foo: string) {}

    static create<T extends Parent>(fooProvider: {foo: string}): T {
        return this.constructor(fooProvider.foo)
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

const instance = Child.create({foo: 'bar'});
instance.logFoo();
```

However, this doesn't work as "Property 'logFoo' does not exist on type 'Parent'.(2339)".

I guess I need some way to specify that the constructor method being called exists on the child class type, but I am not sure how.

I think I can type if specifically, like `Child.create<Child>(foo)`, but that seems redundant. It would be best if TypeScript could infer this type.

A class generic parameter won't work either because this is a static method.

I have checked [Typescript return type of factory method in base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380983/typescript-return-type-of-factory-method-in-base-class) which is similar however is trying to resolve a different use case which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Almost working example:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(protected foo: string) { }

    static create(fooProvider: { foo: string }) {
        return new this(fooProvider.foo)
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

const instance = Child.create({ foo: 'bar' });

instance.logFoo();
```

Compiled code works as expected, however TS does not like it)

I believe you should use some function for factory method, because TS does not allow typing `this` in static methods

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(protected foo: string) { }

    static create(fooProvider: { foo: string }) {
        return new this(fooProvider.foo)
    }
}

type ClassParameters<T> = T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never

const factory = <T extends typeof Parent>(clas: T, args: { foo: ClassParameters<T>[0] }) =>
    clas.create(args) as InstanceType<T>

class Child extends Parent {
    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}


const instance = Child.create({ foo: 'bar' });

const result = factory(Child, { foo: 'bar' }).logFoo()

const expectedError = factory(class A { }, { foo: 'bar' }).logFoo()
```

[Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6wA9ihGggK7BqEIAUADgoWklUgCbQBmhhAXNFIIAligDmASizQAvtlz5SYNMOAFkypLR6FYTAG7D2SBAMzdeAoaLGypOfI%20jI05BCmgokAd2hoAFsIQ2rx6hIbGCAB0OhIKeHJy2GgAnvRI0ADC4FDwCGAAtkgsCBAAPAAqAHzQALzQFdBIAB4sKOwwXr60Ub2IYhAColwmcFK1NWAoKdAA-HDQAl76JvJEJBhcYFQ0M-WVTa2oHX5pSIRccIioaFW0oJACFQA00P2D0joC2ZAQeYXFEzlaoAbQADABdOx1KrxAg5KLADQsWjvKSQaAASQ2U2ASAqZ0qsOwDygWUCIE4LTaJzyNywcJAhDEADFeLR7HDHOsIIQQEgokyxLQAkEYrwJABuOGJeQk4ikaCiJQoPF1cnCSmI5FacxfaAAcgARogDXZpfKNs4kBByCAMPUtjsEClaJkKexXnrLIaTQgzTIJILmWzCBy1gqMC10mx2ABRBBMBDqp3UF33HIwACC0hkXos-F9prswdZ7LiQA)